# How to understand ` catch up` of Java Timer `scheduleAtFixedRate` method and `schedule` method actual run time?

Tags: java

[`java.util.Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask, long, long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long)) the doc say:

> If an execution is delayed for any reason (such as garbage collection or other background activity), two or more executions will occur in rapid succession to "catch up."

And I do a test, code as follow:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(String.format("Task   实际运行时间：%s,需要运行时间：%s", new Date(), new Date(this.scheduledExecutionTime())));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    TimerTask timerTask1 = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(String.format("Task 1 实际运行时间：%s,需要运行时间：%s", new Date().getTime(), new Date(this.scheduledExecutionTime())));
        }
    };
    System.out.println("开始执行时间：" + new Date());
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000);//
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask1, 0, 1000);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

an example of results:

```
开始执行时间：Tue Nov 20 15:56:50 CST 2018 --line 1
Task   实际运行时间：Tue Nov 20 15:56:50 CST 2018,需要运行时间：Tue Nov 20 15:56:50 CST 2018 --line 2
Task 1 实际运行时间：1542700613673,需要运行时间：Tue Nov 20 15:56:50 CST 2018,计时器：1 --line 3
Task 1 实际运行时间：1542700613673,需要运行时间：Tue Nov 20 15:56:51 CST 2018,计时器：2 --line 4
Task   实际运行时间：Tue Nov 20 15:56:53 CST 2018,需要运行时间：Tue Nov 20 15:56:53 CST 2018 --line 5
```

line 3,4 实际运行时间 is same time,and how to understand the `catch up` upon the method doc?

line 2,5 The `Task` run time need at less 3 second,and `period` is 1 second ,and the console why not per 1 second?

Comment: It doesn't answer your question but a `TimerTask` should be fast in order to maintain the scheduling. In other words, it should not take seconds. In case your task has a lot of work to do, create a new thread within the `run` method of your timertask.

Comment: @Robert Kock ,thank you for your reply，I agree with your opinion.